# How to store a photo taken by camera in memory?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am doing a project in android studio. I designed a app and for security purpose i included a feature like, when some one unlock or swipe the phone, the app should take a pic of the person who is doing that action. I am able to take pic **but am unable to store in the gallery**.. can some body help me..

Comment: There are many tutorials available on the internet to implement this. Did have a look at any one of them?

Comment: the tutorials so for i have seen give solution to store image in gallery when there is a click in camera by the user.But i need solution for a image to be stored in memory when the image is taken by the camera without user intervention or without click by the user   (automatically).

Comment: Whenever an image is clicked by the camera (with or without user intervention) you get a Bitmap in the response in `onActivityResult`. You need to save this Bitmap to a file.

Comment: You cannot store pictures in the gallery as the Gallery app is no storage place but just an app that shows all image files on your device. So save the image to file is what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You must broadcast it to MediaScanner then it will be available on gallery.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But if your app propose is security it s not proper action to make that photo public on storage. create internal gallery to show pics taken from your app.